# Most efficient way to exchange data between MATLAB and C++?

Tags: c++, matlab

I'm developing an application where there are two programs, running at the same time: one in C++ and another in MATLAB.

The C++ program generates periodically three numerical values as outputs. The MATLAB program needs an access to the three outputs periodically, but in a different period of time.

Currently, I've solved this using a **`.txt`** file. The C++ writes this file when the routine is done, and the MATLAB reads from it whence it needs.

However, using **`textscan`** command, MATLAB takes around 1.5 ms to read the `.txt` using a Pentium I5-4250U. So, I was wondering if there is a faster way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

### A: Yes, use a messaging layer

If no other services are needed, the C++ side will act as an information provider ( **`ZMQ.PUB`** publisher ) and MATLAB side will act as an information subscriber ( **`ZMQ.SUB`** ).

This way the low-level details related to the messaging are solved by the distributed-processing messaging layer and your solution will benefit from both speed, ready-made tools and can go distributed onto a private grid-computing / cloud-computing architectures, using the same instrumentation, gaining additional performance etc.

ZeroMQ has bindings for both C++ and MATLAB, so that is a place to start and taste the process-to-process messaging-layer approach.

```
% MATLAB script to setup zeromq-matlab
clear all;
if ~ispc
    s1 = zmq( 'subscribe', 'ipc', 'MATLAB' );   %% using IPC transport on <localhost>
else
    disp('0MQ IPC not supported on windows. Setup TCP transport class instead')
    disp('Setting up TCP')
    s1 = zmq( 'subscribe', 'tcp', 'localhost', 5555 );
end

recv_data1 = [];                                %% setup RECV buffer
```

The MATLAB bindings can be found [here](https://github.com/smcgill3/zeromq-matlab).

Having a few floats to send, the latencies will be somewhere under hundreds if not tens of [usec], as your notice mentioned asynchronous mode of data-dispatch, so the localhost will just spend some clocks on data retrieval from localhost ZMQ.SUB-queue.

More complex application-to-application signalling is possible, just get inspired by the [ZeroMQ Guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all)