# How is the Pearson's Correlation calculated in MQL4?

Tags: mql4

Working on an easy that trades correlating pair( hedge ), I need to code a correlation matrix, like the ones on myfxbook, or Oanda.

The main point is I want to be able to loop through each value in the matrix and check if its greater than 85.0 or so.

Comment: Can you at least show us what you got already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `Q:` How is the Pearson's Correlation calculated in MQL4?

### Method A:
 use the `MQL4` to compute the `PearsonCorr_r` directly:

If it is enough to work with the precision of **`double`**, `MQL4` code can implement the process for reasonable-sized vectors of values **`( X[], Y[] )`**

```
#define RET_OK    0
#define RET_ERROR EMPTY
#define VAL_ERROR EMPTY_VALUE

int   PearsonCorr_r( double const &vectorX[], //   |-> INPUT X[]      = { 1, 3,  5,  5,  6 }
                     double const &vectorY[], //   |-> INPUT Y[]      = { 5, 6, 10, 12, 13 }
                     double       &pearson_r  // <=|   returns RESULT = 0.968
                     ){
      double  sumX = 0,
             meanX = 0,
             meanY = 0,
              sumY = 0,
             sumXY = 0,
             sumX2 = 0,
             sumY2 = 0;
          // deviation_score_x[],               // may be re-used for _x^2
          // deviation_score_y[],               // may be re-used for _y^2
          // deviation_score_xy[];
/* =====================================================================
                  DEVIATION SCORES                                       >>> http://onlinestatbook.com/2/describing_bivariate_data/calculation.html
        X[]  Y[]  x      y      xy    x^2    y^2
        1    4   -3     -5      15    9     25
        3    6   -1     -3       3    1      9
        5   10    1      1       1    1      1
        5   12    1      3       3    1      9
        6   13    2      4       8    4     16
       _______________________________________

SUM    20   45    0      0      30   16     60
MEAN    4    9    0      0       6   

       r = SUM(xy) / SQRT(  SUM( x^2 ) * SUM( y^2 ) )
       r =      30 / SQRT( 960 )
       r = 0.968
   =====================================================================
                                                                        */
      int    vector_maxLEN = MathMin( ArrayRange( vectorX, 0 ),
                                      ArrayRange( vectorY, 0 )
                                      );

      if (   vector_maxLEN == 0 ){
             pearson_r = VAL_ERROR;          // STOR VAL ERROR IN RESULT
             return(     RET_ERROR );        // FLAG RET_ERROR in JIT/RET
      }
      for ( int jj = 0; jj < vector_maxLEN; jj++ ){
            sumX += vectorX[jj];
            sumY += vectorY[jj];
      }
      meanX = sumX / vector_maxLEN;          // DIV!0 FUSED
      meanY = sumY / vector_maxLEN;          // DIV!0 FUSED

      for ( int jj = 0; jj < vector_maxLEN; jj++ ){
         // deviation_score_x[ jj] =   meanX - vectorX[jj];  // 
         // deviation_score_y[ jj] =   meanY - vectorY[jj];
         // deviation_score_xy[jj] = deviation_score_x[jj]
         //                        * deviation_score_y[jj];
         //              sumXY    += deviation_score_x[jj]
         //                        * deviation_score_y[jj];
                         sumXY    += ( meanX - vectorX[jj] ) // PSPACE MOTIVATED MINIMALISTIC WITH CACHE-BENEFITS IN PROCESSING
                                   * ( meanY - vectorY[jj] );
         // deviation_score_x[jj] *= deviation_score_x[jj];  // PSPACE MOTIVATED RE-USE, ROW-WISE DESTRUCTIVE, BUT VALUE WAS NEVER USED AGAIN
         //              sumX2    += deviation_score_x[jj]
         //                        * deviation_score_x[jj];
                         sumX2    += ( meanX - vectorX[jj] ) // PSPACE MOTIVATED MINIMALISTIC WITH CACHE-BENEFITS IN PROCESSING
                                   * ( meanX - vectorX[jj] );
         // deviation_score_y[jj] *= deviation_score_y[jj];  // PSPACE MOTIVATED RE-USE, ROW-WISE DESTRUCTIVE, BUT VALUE WAS NEVER USED AGAIN
         //              sumY2    += deviation_score_y[jj]
         //                        * deviation_score_y[jj];
                         sumY2    += ( meanY - vectorY[jj] ) // PSPACE MOTIVATED MINIMALISTIC WITH CACHE-BENEFITS IN PROCESSING
                                   * ( meanY - vectorY[jj] );
      }
      pearson_r = sumXY
                / MathSqrt( sumX2
                          * sumY2
                            );            // STOR RET VALUE IN RESULT
      return( RET_OK );                   // FLAG RET_OK in JIT/RET
```

### Method B:
re-use external Libs having Pearson Correlation in R, MATLAB et al:

One may use a distributed processing using a for example a ZeroMQ messaging infrastructure to request the calculus to be performed outside of the MQL4 / independently from the localhost processing.

If interested, read my [other **posts**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20MQL4%20ZeroMQ) on distributed processes in **`MQL4`** ( a code-example -- just to have some feeling of how the `MQL4` side gets setup -- could be [found **here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29005075/3666197) )
and **`MATLAB`**( a code-example of the ZeroMQ-infrastructure setup could be [found **here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26682434/3666197)

thus allowing to use the MATLAB built-in implementation of Pearson correlation ( remember to properly pre-format data into columns and best if added also a **`DIV!0`**-fusing ), to compute:

```
[ RHO, PVAL ] = corr( vectorX, vectorY, 'type', 'Pearson' );
                                               % note: double-r in corr() 
                                               %            # 'Pearson' is default method
```

Similarly an **`R`**-language has a built-in tool:

```
corr_r <- cor( vecORmatX, vecORmatY, use = "everything", method = "pearson" )
                                                            # "Pearson" is default method
```

Last but not least is a **`python scipy.stats.stats pearsonr`**-implementation as a tool, with both **`float32`** and **`float64`** precisions:

```
>>> from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr as pearson_r
>>>
>>> X = np.zeros( (5,), dtype = np.float32 )
>>> Y = np.zeros( (5,), dtype = np.float32 )
>>>
>>> X[0] =  1; X[1] = 3; X[2] =  5; X[3] =  5; X[4] =  6
>>> Y[0] =  5; Y[1] = 6; Y[2] = 10; Y[3] = 12; Y[4] = 13
>>>
>>> pearson_r( X, Y)
(0.94704783, 0.01451040731338055)
>>>
>>> X = np.zeros( (5,), dtype = np.float64 )
>>> Y = np.zeros( (5,), dtype = np.float64 )
>>>
>>> X[0] =  1; X[1] = 3; X[2] =  5; X[3] = 5; X[4] = 6
>>> Y[0] = 5; Y[1] = 6; Y[2] = 10; Y[3] = 12; Y[4] = 13
>>>
>>> pearson_r( X, Y)
(0.94704783738690446, 0.014510403904375592)
>>>
```

---

### Epilogue:
 <sub>Method A yields results == `python.scipy.stats.stats.pearsonr(X,Y)`</sub>
 <sub>( i.e. the cited onlinestatbook.com result is inaccurate )</sub>

```
2016.10.13 11:31:55.421 ___StackOverflow_Pearson_r_DEMO XAUUSD,H1:
                           PearsonCorr_r( testX, testY, Pearson_r ):= 0.968
                           The actual call returned    aReturnCODE == 0,
                                  whereas the          Pearson_r   == 0.9470
```

Comment: I'm having a a hard time testing the Method A, passing my arrays into the function. I'm  a newbie to stack overflow, I've tried showing my code doesn't show- pls dont me mad at me.Just one problem how do I test your function(Method A). I don't really know how to pass my arrays- that's contains my dataX and dataY to the function

Comment: dataX[5] = {1.2,1.5,4.9,9.8} dataY[5] = {2.2,-4.7, 8.7,9.0}. This is my data, I dont know how to pass it to the pearsonCorr_r function.

Comment: Also the &Pearson_r argument, is that the number of elements in the datasets? What do I put there?

Comment: And where is the problem, Dave? What have you tried so far to compile and call in your own code? Could you post an example of the use you were trying so far to show, where have you succeeded and where there are any issues you face after your own testing? Thanks.